# How to use updated variable values in two separate executable using same shared library

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I am having a shared library libshared.so, i have two executables e1 and e2 using the same 
    shared library. e1 is started and running which updates the value "i" in shared library from
    0 to 1. simultaneously now e2 starts running and now e2 should see the value updated by e1. 
    this is not the basic working principle of shared library. But is there any way to achieve
    this by altering linker flags.

Comment: AFAIK you can't, you need shared memory (see [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)).

Comment: Both of those processes will load a different instance of libshared.so in their memory space; you need a shared memory piece.